# Two React projects on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, deployment

I have 2 applications A & B. Now I want to route from A to B on a particular page but I am facing some issues related to authentication because of which it is redirecting to the login page in B.

I want to test it locally and for that, I want to run both applications at the same time on the **same port** (8001) as there is some information stored in local storage.

The reason to run on the same port is that if I run both the apps on **different ports** (8001 and 8002), the local storage will be different for different domains and it can't be shared.

I don't want to deploy on the dev environment because every time I make changes, I have to build and deploy again and again, which makes it a tedious task.

Is there any tool or way by which I can run both apps locally on the same port?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.techomoro.com/multi-zones-combine-multiple-next-js-apps/amp/

Comment: There is no direct way to run to servers on the same port, however if you want to have two servers that appear to share the same IP and port, you could use a load balancer like Citrix' NetScaler. The NetScaler would examine each request, and then route the request to the correct server backend. They could both be on the same server, but using different ports.